# How can I get a summarized callstack of an exception in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0

In Cakephp 2.6 I have registered an custom exception handler in the core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Exception.handler', function($error) {

    $lMessage = "Message: ". $error->getMessage(). "\r\n";
    $lMessage += "\r\n";

    ob_start();
    var_dump($error->getTrace()); // attach the callstack
    $lMessage += ob_get_clean();

    Mail::send("xxxxxxxxxx", "Exception", $lMessage);
});
```

**The Problem:** The mail cannot be sent, because the callstack is too long. The callstack has a string with 137837 rows of code. It is so long, because it contains the code from the framework.

**Question:** How can I get a more summarized callstack that has more the focus on my own written code?

**Additional Code → How I throw the exception for this example:**

```
// Call via the browser: http://hostname/Test/test

// The Controller
class TestController extends AppController
{
    function test()
    {
        $lResult = $this->Test->TestException();
    }
}

// The Model
class Test extends AppModel 
{
    public function TestException()
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some sort of recursion in the code? 137k rows of call stack seems too much even for a large framework.

Comment: @Dmitry: I have added the code how I throw this exception that results in 137k rows in the callstack.

Comment: Please share the callstack, 137k steps is absurd, there must be a problem somewhere.